# Query DB2 9.7 using .NET 4

Tags: c#, .net, db2, adapter

In my company DB2 9.7 is used so I need to work with this database using C# .Net 4. First I installed the db2 dataserver client and found in C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN\netf20 the IBM.Data.DB2.dll library. But this library is only for .NET 2 and I I'm getting error when try to use it in my .NET 4 project. I cant use .NET 2 because all of my libraries(like lib. for Excel parsing) are using .NET4. I can't change anything in db2 server side (like fixpacks). Please help me to find a solution.

Comment: What's the exact error you're getting? The 2.0 DLL should still at least work when you're running. However, there should also be a 4.0 folder you can use, as well inside the SQLLIB\BIN folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .NET 2 dll should run in .NET 4.
But a real .NET 4 dll can be found in "c:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN\netf40"